# Using a UITapGestureRecognizer to play/pause audio

Tags: ios, swift

This seems like a fairly simple task, but have been trying for a while to figure it out... I have set up a UITapGestureRecognizer to play an audio file from the bundle. That works well, but I would like to have the user be able to tap the item again and have the audio stop. Basically have the ability to start and replay the audio by tapping the object with single taps.

```
    @IBAction func page1Tapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let url:URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Opening Solo", withExtension: "mp3")!
    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: nil)
    } catch {
        return
    }

    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer.play()

    if audioPlayer.isPlaying {
     audioPlayer.stop()
    } else {
     audioPlayer.play()
     }
}
```

Here is the function that I have created. The audio only plays and just restarts at 0 with every tap at this point.

Any help is incredibly appreciated!!

Comment: Why do you call `play` no matter what?

Comment: Hello! That was me trying to figure out how to work this functionality :) haha

Comment: Wait a minute...why do you play if the audio player is already playing? Why do you stop if the audio player has already stopped...? `if audioPlayer.isPlaying {
     audioPlayer.play()
    } else {
     audioPlayer.stop()
     }`

Comment: Sorry, had it backwards, already been down voted apparently... Whoops! I guess that is what learning is all about :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This because every click creates a new re-assings the old instance , you can declare the player as instance variable

```
var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?
```

and check it's value before assigning

```
 if audioPlayer == nil
 {
    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: nil)
    audioPlayer.play()
 }
 else
 {
      if audioPlayer.isPlaying {
          audioPlayer.stop()
       } else {
          audioPlayer.play()
       }
 }
```

Comment: Ok, this makes sense! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Good answer (voted), although the code would be a little cleaner if the audioPlayer were a lazy var.